# Get complete count from database rails 5

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on a dashboard where I want to get a count based on a boolean record because students can click whether they have completed a module or not, here is the boolean in the database.

[image: database]

On the dashboard I have

[image: dash]

I can get the full module count by doing this `<%= CourseModule.count %>` but I want to set the complete count only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scope your collection with a [`where`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) query:

```
<%= CourseModule.where(complete: true).count %>
```

Or to use it at multiple places, define a [scope](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) in your model `CourseModule` as below:

```
class CourseModule
  scope :completed, -> { where(complete: true) }
end
```

and use it everywhere as follows:

```
CourseModule.completed
 # => ActiveRecord Relation of completed records

CourseModule.completed.count
 # => Count of completed records
```

Comment: Ohh I also tried `<%= CourseModule.count(:complete) %>` so I was close haha. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah. Check the updated answer for a more usable approach.